# How to detect the "key up" event of the CTRL key when releasing CTRL-F?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect the "key up" event of the CTRL key when releasing CTRL+F in the browser. I have tried this:

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.ctrlKey){ // note that I'm not even checking for the F key here
            console.log("CTRL up");
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work, the event is not triggered. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you can add it before the function, if I'm not mistaken, so like:
`$(...).keyup('f', function(e)...` . Just don't forget the Mac users either:
`if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)` :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you are checking that the CTRL key was let go, then it would be false on the event, no?  Cause it's no longer held.  You probably want to target the keyCode or the which on the event and see if it is the ctrl key.

Answer (score 1):

`e.ctrlKey` returns false on keyUp event and true on keyDown. You can test `(e.keyCode === 17)` condition.

Comment: I actually like that nuance in the first sentence; it means you can simply listen to both up & down, and whether `ctrlKey == true` is your condition, instead of writing different logic and listening to up and down separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can always do:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 70 || e.keyCode === 102)) // f or F
    alert("Ctrl+F was pressed!!");
});
```

from your code:

- never use `keyup`, by that time the browser already fired its own event and the event will never be bubble down to the document again, at least you should use `keydown`
- you will never be able to override the browser behavior, in this case, bring the search input box

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. I always find it easiest to output the `e` variable in order to see exactly what's going on and filter down from there. 
See my jsfiddle for a working example.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.key == 'Control') {
    console.log("CTRL keyup event.");
  }
});
```